# Is there a way by which i can control the number of letters after which the ellipsis appears in text-overflow?

Tags: css

I have a div element to display the status of an item. If the status text is too large, i want to wrap and display ellipsis. Below is the CSS of the item.

```css
.item-status {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-spacing: -0.17em;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    font-size: 8pt;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 1px;
    text-indent: .25em;
    min-width: 3.25em;
    max-width: 7em;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

And the corresponding div is

```
<div class="item-status">This is an open item to test ellipsis</div>
```

For this text the ellipsis appears after "o" like

> This is an o... (after 12 chars)

There is another div with the same class

```
<div class="item-status">Some one is looking into this. Please wait.</div>
```

For this text the ellipsis appears as

> Some one i... (after 10 chars)

There is a requirement to display the ellipsis consistently after a specified number of characters like after 10 characters. Is there any property that can be set to control where the ellipsis appears in a wrapped text?

Comment: you have to adjust this manually with the width of the container... Font-size, font-weight and font-family will matter in this by adjusting it manually...

Comment: Although you probably don't want to, you could use a [monospace font](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/BZXfc/).

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish. This behavior is exactly what i need, but you guessed it right, the fonts go for a toss. So as other members have suggested, i am going to play around with the width of the container to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with CSS, but you can do it with Javascript.

```
// gets characters 1 - 10 in newstr
var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
var newstr = str.substr(0, 10);
newstr += '...';
```

Comment: As pointed out in earlier comments you actually can achieve something like this with CSS, just not based on the number of characters but rather based on the width of the container.

Comment: Of course. But the original question asked about a consistent number of characters, not adjusting the width of the container.

Comment: Thanks @magi182. If adjusting the width of the container yields consistent result, then i may actually prefer that way. But if it is not consistent, i will script it as you have suggested.

Comment: @gshank, many attempt such as this has run aground in th' rocky shoals.

Comment: Yes, that rings an alarm. So i decided not to use the script to control the display.

Comment: @gshank, not to speak for Jared, but to speak for Jared... I think he was referring to the infinitely fiddly nature of trying to accomplish this with CSS.  Once you get an oldster on your site with their font size turned up, all your careful CSS tweaks are out the window.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time fiddling with the CSS, found that there is no direct way to achieve this (other than adjusting the font-family, size etc.). So for now, suggested a workaround to float the div 'left' and increase min-width. This way the div has the entire width to display the message. No need for overflow :)